# SQL where parenthesis

Tags: sql

The below query is also fetching deleted orders. Is that because of the 'where' clause parenthesis?

```
select * 
from tbl_orders or
join tbl_company co on or.orderid = co.orderid
where ((or.orderstatus = 'placed') or
       (or.orderstatus = 'confirmed' and co.orderstatus = 'unavailable'))
  and or.orderdeleted <> 'Yes';
```

This is also returning orders that have `or.orderdeleted = 'Yes'`

Comment: We can't really answer your question because we don't your data or the intended logic here.  You might want to add more details to your question.

Comment: I really doubt there are any rows it your result where `or.orderdeleted = 'Yes'`. There may be rows with `'yes'` *(all lower case)* or possibly even `'Yes '` *(With unintended white space)*

Comment: Instead of a `select *`, try a select of just those columns from the WHERE and see if you spot the reason

Comment: Remove ambiguity - make the or.orderdeleted <> 'Yes' the _first_ entry in the where clause.   Check what records this extracts - using suggesting by @Hans Kesting .  Then start to apply orderstatus criteria individually.